# Why Firestore Recycler Options showing error?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

It is showing error here

```
FirestoreRecyclerOptions<firestorereycler> allfirestorerecycler= new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<firestorereycler>()
            .setQuery(QueryApni.firestorereycler.class)
            .build();
```

I am using this library

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0'
```

Comment: You should also pass a query to the `setQuery()` method, as the first argument.

Comment: Sorry,I didn't get your point.

Comment: Check [this](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/firestore/readme/) out. Ex: `FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Chat> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Chat>().setQuery(query, Chat.class).build();`.

Comment: Same error occurring

Comment: What is the error you get? Please see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as a single line will be hard to help with.

Comment: Error is that firebaserecycleroption become red means it ask to create a class. But why?

Answer (score 3):

If you add libraries , you will not get an error.

Go to AndroidStudio -> Tools -> Firebase -> Cloud Firestore.  And follow steps. Everything will set automatically.

In addition , add this to build.gradle(Module:...) -> dependencies ----->
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:7.1.1'

After these steps . Everything will be ok.
I managed to run it after following these procedures.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Official Documentation](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/firestore/readme/) `setQuery()` requires 2 arguments, a **query** and a **class**.

```
FirestoreRecyclerOptions<firestorereycler> allfirestorerecycler= new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<firestorereycler>()
            .setQuery(<QUERY>,QueryApni.firestorereycler.class)
            .build();
```